# Vuetify v-navigation-drawer cannot overflow button

Tags: vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

I have a `v-navigation-drawer` and it's design must include a toggle expand button that overflows the drawer itself like so:

[image]

But for some unknown reason, I  can't remove the overflow hidden property.

I tried to remove it like this:

```
    .v-navigation-drawer {
      overflow: auto;

      .v-navigation-drawer__content {
        overflow-x: auto;
      }
    }
```

No success:

[image]

Here the codepend reproducing the issue: https://codepen.io/aug-riedinger/pen/poLjJyq

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as kael said, you need to set the overflow property to `visible` for normal and mini variant. Like this:

```css
.v-navigation-drawer--mini-variant, .v-navigation-drawer {
  overflow: visible !important;
  
}

.expand-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -14px;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  .v-btn {
    margin: auto;
    border: thin solid white !important;
  }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: I did try with `overflow-x: visible;` and it did not work but `overflow: visible` does! Not clear why but thanks!

Comment: That's because internally the navigation drawer component has the css property `overflow` set to hidden.  And that's the one you need to override.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/2074736

You want `visible` not `auto`, and you also have to set `overflow-y: visible` for that to actually take effect.